# Replacing A Ceramic Hob With An Induction Hob

Tags: electrical, appliances

If I were to replace my ceramic hob in my kitchen at some point in the future with an induction hob, would any rewiring be needed or from an electrical point of view, would it be a straight swap?

(UK, currently both the hob and oven are on the cooker circuit)

Comment: You can download and check the user manual for the new unit.

Comment: this question belongs in "DIY"

Comment: What is the amp or watt rating for old and new?

Comment: I won't know what watt rating the new would be until I eventually look to replace it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the spur to your hob is rated for sufficient current for whatever induction hob you may buy in the future **and** the oven, the two hobs are interchangable without any rewiring.

The only caveat is that if your ceramic hob is single-phase, you must get an induction hob that supports single phase. Most UK marketed ones will.

---

The more powerful induction hobs require >30A nominal so a standard 32A rated spur may be insufficient for the hob alone, let alone an induction hob and and oven.

As such it would make sense to install a seperate spur for the hob when you change over to induction at a later date. I would go for cabling and switches designed for a 40A or 50A spur.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the electrical - nicely covered in the other answer, you need to check the physical dimensions.

Many are standard but some are definitely not - DeDeitrich is not standard... I had to replace mine and found that out.. so check the hole size.